# How can I use separate class to be used in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a ruby class which I want to use it as a library in a rails app, how (what folder) should I include it in the application?

I want to use the class in my controller. Do I just simply use 'require' to include the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a require in the controller assuming the file is somewhere in your load path.  I follow a few simple strategies:

1. If its a class that adds plugin like behavior but isnt quite large enough to write a plugin, I just put it in config/initializers since they the lib is in the load path and all the files are required for you on startup.  No additional requires needed.
2. The other option is to put them in the lib directory and just require them when you need them.  If you are using rails 3, the lib directory is not a part of the load path and you will need to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend throwing it in the `lib` folder - you then can `require` it from your `config/environment.rb` file and if I recall correctly, that should be all you need to do.